# Query execution taking time in Presto with pinot connector

Tags: olap, trino

We are using Apache pinot as source system. We have loaded 10GB TPCH data into pinot. We are using Presto as query execution engine, using pinot connector.

We are trying with simple configuration. Presto installed on CentOS machine with 8CPUs and 64GB RAM. Only one instance of worker running with embedded coordinator. Pinot is installed on CentOS machine with 4 CPUs and 64 GB RAM. One Controller,one broker,one server and one zookeeper are running.

Running a query on Lineitem table involving group by roll-up, is taking 23 seconds. Around 20 seconds is spent in transferring 2.3GB data from pinot to presto.

In another query, involving join between Lineitem,Nation,Partsupply,Region with group by cube is taking around 2 minutes. Data transfer is taking around 25 seconds in this. Most of the remaiy time is spent in join and aggregation computation.

Is this normal performance with presto-pinot?
If not,what am I missing?
Do I, need to increase hardware? Increase number of presto/pinot processes?
Any specific presto properties I should consider modifying?

Thanks for your help in advance

Answer (score 1):

Please list the queries so that we can provide a better answer. At a high level, Presto Pinot connector tries to pushdown most of the computation (filter, aggregation, group by) to Pinot and minimize the amount of data needed to pull from Pinot.

There are always queries that require a full table scan and computation cannot be pushed to pinot. Query latency can be higher in such cases. Pinot recently added a streaming api that can improve the latency further.